# Probabilistic capacity after some time in operation- ANYLOGIC

Tags: anylogic

The transition set the resource pool capacity to 0 once the scrap is above 3,000. However, is there a way I can include a probabilistic approach which means once the scrap is above 3,000 the capacity decreases to zero with some probability as the time passes instead of using a timeout in transition?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhvU4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The capacity field is a dynamic code field so you can use this:

`(something > 3000 && randomTrue(0.5)) 0 : currentCapacity`